# screenshot with timer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, screenshot

Hey Guys i have 1 More Problem . i want to take Screenshot with timer its works but it only take 1 screenshot after that it give me error i dont know what to do here is my CODE

i will show u error also

```
private static void GetScreenShot()
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);

        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

        bitmap.Save("screenshot.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetScreenShot();
        email.Send("HAMMAD");
        MessageBox.Show("DONE");

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a counter and then assign counter value to the filename.

**Note 1:** `Bitmap` parent class `Image` implements `IDisposable` interface so you could enclose the `Bitmap` class declaration within `using block` to make sure its disposal.

**Note 2:** `Graphics` class implements `IDisposable` interface so you could enclose the `Graphics` class declaration within `using block` to make sure its disposal.

Try This:

```
int counter = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter =counter+1;
    GetScreenShot(counter);
    email.Send("HAMMAD");
    MessageBox.Show("DONE");

}

private static void GetScreenShot(int counter)
{
    using(Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 
                                          Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height))
   {
      using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image))
      {
         graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
      }
      bitmap.Save("screenshot"+counter+".jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);       
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** for sending proper screenshot in email try this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter =counter+1;
    GetScreenShot(counter);
    email.Send("screenshot"+counter+".jpeg");
    MessageBox.Show("DONE");
}
```

Comment: its Works 1 more Prob is that its send me on email but everytime it send screenshot.jpeg

Comment: You didn't show the code for sending the email, but I guess you need to change the file name there, too. You need to send the *latest* file, not always `screenshot.jpg`. Or you could just pass the dynamically created file name to `email.Send` as a parameter.

Comment: @Munnoo: You are welcome :) , glad tobe Help of you.